# Cannot type letters and numbers

Tags: keyboard

I am experiencing a very strange behaviour of my keyboard:

My letter keys are not working as expected. When I try to enter some text, most of the keys are not reacting. If they are reacting, they show a strange behaviour. For instance, pressing the 's' -key will take a screenshot. The numbers are not working, too. Other keys such as enter, delete, space, tab, and the arrow keys work as expected. 
In , when booting I have to enter a password to unlock my encrypted disk. This works, too.

I experienced this behaviour once before. Then I freshly reinstalled ubuntu and used a backup of my home drive. So maybe my keyboard is misconfigured. But, I really don't know what's going wrong. Maybe something is wrong with the fn key. I checked the bios, but there everything seems to be configured correctly. Disabling the fn key would be a solution for me.

Does someone know what's going on with my keyboard or has some tips?

Thanks in advance,
Richard

Comment: @user68186 no, there was no liquid. But I am afraid the keyboard is broken...

Comment: Try booting from a LiveUSB (Try Ubuntu option) and see if the problems are there as well. If so, you have eliminated configuration problem and it is hardware failure for sure.